# If arrays are passed by reference, how can the following work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var myarray = []
var array1 = [1,2,3]
myarray.push(array1)
array1 =[2,3,4]
myarray.push(array1)
console.log(myarray)
```

I get

> [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 2, 3, 4 ] ].

Shouldn't it be

> [ [ 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 3, 4 ] ]

if I am passing by reference?

Thank you

edit: I am guessing it is because  = [2,3,4] creates a new object and assigns `array1` to refer to it rather than vice versa

Comment: Your edit is correct; `array1` is overwritten.

Comment: Like if I do myarray[0][0]= 99, followed by
console.log(array1), i would get [99,2,3]. I thought this was pass by reference since I can change array1 by changing myarray[0]. edit: thank you

Comment: JavaScript is always pass by value. For objects (including arrays) the value that is copied just happens to be a reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not modifying the variable (array), you're reassigning a new value.

```js
var myarray = [];
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
myarray.push(array1);
array1.push(2, 3, 4); // Modifying the array in memory.
//myarray.push(array1);
console.log(myarray);
```

Comment: This answer is perfect

Answer (score 2):

You need to mutate elements of the `array1` to keep the reference. Not re-assign it.

```js
var myArray = []
var array1 = [1,2,3]

myArray.push(array1)
array1.forEach((e, i) => array1[i] = array1[i] + 1)
myArray.push(array1)

console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference means if two variable are referencing same object/array then modifying(changing property/deleting property) of one will change the other variable too.

```js
let array1 = [1,2,3];
let array2 = array1;     //creating a reference
array1[0] = "something"; //modifying
console.log(array1)
console.log(array2)
```

Reference doesnot mean that if you two variables are referencing same object/array then assigning a new value to one of them to change the other.

```js
let array1 = [1,2,3];
let array2 = array1;        //creating a reference
array1 = ["something",2,3]; //Assigning a new value
console.log(array1)
console.log(array2)
```

If you want to change create a reference than change the first element of `myarray` and push that into the `myarray`

```js
var myarray = []
var array1 = [1,2,3]
myarray.push(array1)
myarray[0] =[2,3,4]
myarray.push(myarray[0])

console.log(myarray[0]) //[2,3,4]
console.log(myarray[1]) //[2,3,4]

myarray[0][1] = "something else" //change both elements

console.log(myarray[0]) //[2,"something else",4]
console.log(myarray[1]) //[2,"something else",4]
```